# Emailjs in my react app has stopped working after deployment

Tags: reactjs, deployment, gitlab, netlify

I have deployed my react app through gitlab and netlify. I think that i have setup everything correctly in my .gitlab-ci.yml and environment variables in gitlab correctly, however I am still getting a user id is required error now in both development and production builds.

[React Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j45qh.png)[.gitlab-ci.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRacF.png)

```
import { useState } from "react";
import emailjs from "emailjs-com";

import './Contact.css';

const Contact = () => {

  const [ status, setStatus ] = useState('Send');

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setStatus('Sending...')
    const { fromName, email, subject, message } = e.target.elements;
    const templateParams = {
      fromName: fromName.value,
      email: email.value,
      subject: subject.value,
      message: message.value,
    };

  try {
    const response = await emailjs.send(
      process.env.REACT_APP_SERVICE_ID,
      process.env.REACT_APP_YOUR_TEMPLATE_ID,
      templateParams,
      process.env.REACT_APP_YOUR_API_KEY,
    );

    if (response.status === 200) {
      setStatus("Message sent!");
      e.target.reset();
      setTimeout(() => {
        setStatus("Send");
      }, 5000);
    } else {
      setStatus("Failed to send message. Please try again");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error sending message:", error);
    setStatus("Failed to send message. Please try again.");
  }
};
```

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build project:
  stage: build
  image : node:16
  script:
    - cd portfolio
    - |
      if [ "$SET_PERMISSIONS" = "true" ]; then
        chmod +x node_modules/.bin/react-scripts
      fi
    - npm install
    - echo "REACT_APP_SERVICE_ID=$REACT_APP_SERVICE_ID" >> .env.production
    - echo "REACT_APP_YOUR_API_KEY=$REACT_APP_YOUR_API_KEY" >> .env.production
    - echo "REACT_APP_YOUR_TEMPLATE_ID=$REACT_APP_YOUR_TEMPLATE_ID" >> .env.production
    - npm run build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/

netlify:
  stage: deploy
  image: node:16
  script:
    - cd portfolio
    - npm install -g netlify-cli
    - netlify deploy --dir=build --prod
```

This is my first time using all of these features and deploying in general

EDIT - I have fixed my development build. However I am still having issues with undefined environment variables once deployed. I originally did not have my environment variables set up with netlify as well so I did that and made the following changes to my .gitlab-ci.yml however I am still at a loss.

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build project:
  stage: build
  image : node:16
  script:
    - cd portfolio
    - |
      if [ "$SET_PERMISSIONS" = "true" ]; then
        chmod +x node_modules/.bin/react-scripts
      fi
    - npm install
    - echo "REACT_APP_SERVICE_ID=$REACT_APP_SERVICE_ID" >> .env
    - echo "REACT_APP_YOUR_API_KEY=$REACT_APP_YOUR_API_KEY" >> .env
    - echo "REACT_APP_YOUR_TEMPLATE_ID=$REACT_APP_YOUR_TEMPLATE_ID" >> .env
    - npm run build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/

netlify:
  stage: deploy
  image: node:16
  script:
    - cd portfolio
    - npm install -g netlify-cli
    - |
      NETLIFY_AUTH_TOKEN=$NETLIFY_AUTH_TOKEN \
      NETLIFY_SITE_ID=$NETLIFY_SITE_ID \
      REACT_APP_SERVICE_ID=$REACT_APP_SERVICE_ID \
      REACT_APP_YOUR_API_KEY=$REACT_APP_YOUR_API_KEY \
      REACT_APP_YOUR_TEMPLATE_ID=$REACT_APP_YOUR_TEMPLATE_ID \
      netlify deploy --dir=build --prod
```